Why did the calendar style of mat-date break?
I used mat-date in my Angular project, but when clicking the icon to display the calendar, I found that the styles were all broken
displayed calendar effect

I tried commenting out the styles of other component libraries imported in styles.scss, but the display effect of mat-date didn't change
Do you guys know why this happen?  thanks!
Here is my code：
package.json
"@angular/material": "^17.3.3",  
"@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^17.3.3", 

index.html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />

styles.scss
@use '@angular/material' as mat;  
 @include mat.all-component-typographies();  
 @include mat.core();

date.component.html
<mat-form-field> 
    <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label> 
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker"> 
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle> 
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker> 
</mat-form-field>


I find the reason ,seems because one of the related module haven't been imported.
After importing the module, the date calender is ok.
